# How can I clear Magento Cache when using a Memcached server

Tags: magento, memcached

I've been running on a problem for about two weeks.
I Have a magento which is configured to use a memcache server.

Recently, I got to change the server storing my magento application.
I installed my new server, and just get my magento app up and running on the new server, with one change : I changed the database user and password used to connect to the database server.
I changed from userold to usernew. 
This change takes place in my `local.xml` file.

But now, when I active the magento cache, Magento tries to connect to my database with the old username : userold.
I've tried all things :

```
rm -fR var/ 
/etc/init.d/memcache restart
killall memcached
reboot the entire server running memcached!
```

I still have my cache problem ! I can't get my

Where does this "userold" value is fuc*** stored ?

Any help would really be appreciated ! :)

Hugues.

Comment: use grep to find userold in files, and in a database dump. If you still can't find it, use a debugger like pdt+xdebug to find out what happens.

Comment: Bonjour Grégoire,
userold n'apparait dans aucun fichiers. Ensuite, j'ai vérifié en base, il n'apparait pas non plus, et d'ailleurs c'est logique, Magento essaye de se connecter à la base avec userold, il ne va pas d'abord regarder en base quel utilisateur utiliser avant de se connecter... logique.
Par ailleurs, je ne peux pas debugguer pour le moment par manque de temps. 
Ta réponse n'est pas du tout pertinente malheureusement.
Tu aurais put répondre "va voir sur google" que ça reviendrais au même...

Answer (score 3):

telnet into the memcache instance and issue a `flush_all` command.  Restarting the memcache server should have already flushed it, but sometimes its worth a try...

Comment: This does work, but I would love to know why "Flush Magento Cache" and "Flush Cache Storage" don't work in the Admin for memcached.

Answer (score 1):

Magento uses TwoLevels backend for caching.

Cache stores to both of them. 
And according to Zend's code, Magento reads from fast, and then from slow, if nothing returns.

You have to flush memcache and remove /var/cache at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

start a new instance of memcache on a new port eg 11212

now specify this new port in local.xml

that should ensure that it is talking to a new instacne not the old.. or

use htop / top find find the psid of memcache and kill xxxx